# How to change a function noted as a var from an external file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, file, external

Question might've confused you, so basically: There are some functions in the `window` that were created by an external JS file. Now, I want to add some code to the function but through my own external JS file. Example:

```
var aa = {
  bb: function(e){
    console.log("Hello "+e);
  },
  cc: "Goodbye"
}
```

Now in this example I want to change the function `aa.bb` without affecting `e`. Is there any practical way of doing this? Thanks, and jQuery is an option here.

**CLARIFICATION**: I want here to leave the function as-is without having to copy everything. Using the example above, is there a way to add `console.log("foo")` to the function?

Comment: change the function to what?

Comment: Probably not, you would have to copy the whole code and write something like `aa.bb = function(e) { console.log("Hello "+e); /* New Code */};`

Comment: So there is basically a function `window.aa.bb` defined, and you are asking how to assign your own `window.aa.bb` function? -.-

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, added clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is either very unclear or very easy. To solve what you've described in your question, the following will do it

```
var aa = {
    bb: function(e){
        console.log("Hello "+e);
    },
    cc: "Goodbye"
}

aa.bb('bar'); // Hello bar

aa.bb = function(e) {
    console.log('foo ' + e)
}

aa.bb('bar'); // foo bar
```